# Display data with Django

Tags: mysql, django, django-models, django-views, django-queryset

I'm a beginner at Django and Python.

I'm trying to query a MySQL database.
Entering the data from the admin section works fine. Queering the database doesn't give an error, but it doesn't work.

I tried querying from shell, and it worked perfectly. However, querying from the code section doesn't.

The models.py looks like this:

```
class Courses(models.Model):
    course_title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    course_image = models.ImageField(upload_to='course_images/')
    course_duration = models.TimeField()

    def __str__(self): return self.course_title
```

The views.py looks like this;

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import Courses


def homepage(request):
    cos = Courses.objects.all()
    context={
     'courses': cos
    }

    return render(request, "main/home.html", context)
```

The home.html looks like this:

```
{% for cos in courses %}
{{cos}}
{% endfor %}
```

I tried using `Courses.objects.all` and also `Courses.objects.all()` but it still won't work.

The urls.py looks like this:

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

app_name = "main"

urlpatterns = [
    path("", views.homepage, name="homepage"),
    path('about/', views.about, name='about'),
    path('home/', views.home, name'home'),
]
```

The projects urls.py is:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [ path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('main.urls')),
    ]
```

I really need some assistance.

Comment: Can you share your urls.py? And the url that you are accessing?

Comment: I just edited the question. Please have a look. The urls.py is at the bottom @lainShelvington

Comment: "It doesn't work" is not a problem description. Which URL are you going to? What did you see? What error did you get? Also, that appears to be the app URLs, also share the project URLs.

Comment: I'm going to the "home" url, it doesn't say anything. There are no errors displayed. I've edited the code and added the project url and apps urls too.

Comment: what is the error.

You said you have error but you didn't specified the actual error.

Comment: I don't get any errors. It doesn't give me any errors. It just doesn't display the data it should get from the database. That's the issue I'm faced with.

Comment: I think everything is fine. you just print the length of 'cos' ( print(len(cos) ) in views.py and see that print will give length 0 or >0? I think it will give you length 0 that's why you didn't get your required output.

Comment: @MkPatel it gave me length 0. I'm stuck with this one.

Comment: @user3288057 then please check your database either it is empty or there is something error in the database connection.